# JQuery rolling - stop previous & generalize

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have code like this:

JavaScript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("a.link1").click(function (){
        //$(this).stop().preventDefault().animate(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#link1").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        //});
  });

  $("a.link2").click(function (){
        //$(this).stop().preventDefault().animate(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#link2").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        //});
  });

  $("a.link3").click(function (){
        //$(this).stop().preventDefault().animate(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#link3").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        //});
  });
});
```

Body of HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
  <a href='#link1' class="link1">LINK 1</a>
  <a href='#link2' class="link2">LINK 2</a>
  <a href='#link3' class="link3">LINK 3</a>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <a name="link1" id="link1"></a>
  <!--some text-->
  <a name="link2" id="link2"></a>
  <!--some text-->
  <a name="link3" id="link3"></a>
  <!--some text-->
</div>
```

Please help me with this:

1. Stop doesn't seem to work the way I wanted. I want to somehow stop previous rolling when another link is activated.
2. Is there any way of generalization of the jQuery part. I have more than 3 menu links and I don't want to make a special function for each.

Thank you very much for your help.
Gomi

Comment: You could set a general class on all anchors and an id to each of them. Then you could do 
$(a.link).click(function(){
id = $(this).attr('id');
and use the id to scrollTop.
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generalize by extracting the click callbacks to a common function:

```
var linkClickCallback = function(selector){
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top
        }, 2000);
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("a.link1").click(linkClickCallback.bind(null, '#link1'));
   $("a.link2").click(linkClickCallback.bind(null, '#link2'));
   $("a.link3").click(linkClickCallback.bind(null, '#link3'));
});
```

Note that in the linkClickCallback i also wrote the proper use of stop() method.

**EDIT:**

This will work for all items in menu:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#menu a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        linkClickCallback('#' + this.className);
   });
});
```

with the same linkClickCallback function.

Comment: It works, thank you. I have two questions:

1) Is there any way to generalize it even more (somethink like "for all links in #menu do..")

2) Is there any way to add there that `.preventDefault()`? It's smoother with it (it doesn't "blink to anchor" before executing roll)

Comment: I updated my answear accordingly. If that works for you you can mark my post as the accepted answear.

Comment: Hmm... I don't know why, but it doesn't work. In fact, I have those links as `<div id='menu'><ul><a href='#link1' class='link1'><li>Something</li></a>...</div>`, but in my opinion, there should be no difference (I've tried also use caller `#menu > ul > a`, but it did not help).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah just generalise a function like this and then inside the function, look for the caller (this):

```
$("#menu a").click(function(e){
    var t = $(this)
    $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: t.offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```